# How to return to process a previous row if your script is processing line-by-line?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

Here is my sample list:

```
AAA BBB CCC1
DDD EEE FFF1
GGG HHH III1           <----- I want to remove this
GGG HHH III3 >>updated <----- I want to keep this
JJJ KKK LLL7
```

As I'm traversing the list using a For Loop, I want to take note of every row that has a ">>updated" in it and go back one row and remove the older row (not updated) and then move forward to the next row after the ">>updated" row. So basically my final output would be:

```
AAA BBB CCC1
DDD EEE FFF1
GGG HHH III3
JJJ KKK LLL7
```

I am using awk to parse the values of the other fields from a shell script, but I'm just not quite sure how to do this backwards and forwards step. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the `awk` you have coded so far, will be a good start to help you.

Comment: How big is the real list?  If it is not too large then a possible solution is to read the whole lot into an array.  Random access is then easy.

Comment: Well the actual columns are kind of ugly. They don't quite line up, some fields are empty, I also have to substitute some fields from column A into Column E, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '{a=$0;getline; if ($0~/>>updated/)print $1,$2,$3; else print a,"\n"$0}' file
AAA BBB CCC1
DDD EEE FFF1
GGG HHH III3
JJJ KKK LLL7
```

Comment: Hi again @sudo_O So I'm actually reading a file, doing a `For i in 'cat myfile'` loop to read through it sequentially and using awk to parse each field in every row and writing the output to a tempfile. Based on your recommendation above, should I go through the pass once and write everything to a file, then go through it a second time using the tac cmd?

Comment: Ugh, the proper way to loop over a file is `while read i; do ... done <myfile`

Comment: @tripleee I can do that too :) but that still doesn't solve my problem of when I get to a row where there is a field matching ">>updated", how do I go back one row and replace the contents of the older row with the new row.

Comment: No, no, no.. `awk` reads files record by record you don't need too loop over the file using `bash`! Given a file of the format in your question my answers will do the required transformation. You already have 2 working solutions. Either your problem is solved, or your question is misleading!?

Comment: @sudo_O ah ok, I just realized what that second "tac" does. Oops, that makes sense :) Off to try it. Thank you!

Comment: @sudo_O sorry to bug you again. This code almost does what I need, but does it the opposite. I'll try to rephrase. Let's say I have Line #3-ORIG and Line #4-ORIG>>updated. This code is currently printing line #3 and ignoring line #4.  I actually want to do the opposite. Print line #4 and remove #3.  It could also be possible that since my server does not have **tac** I had to improvise and use `awk '{a[i++]=$0} END {for (j=i-1; j>=0;) print a[j--] }' file` instead

Comment: @fembot see updated answer. You question gave the impression that the 3rd field of the previous line should be updated by the 3rd field of the following `>>updated` line. You new requirement is simple.

Comment: If you're considering using getline, make sure you fully understand all of the caveats described at http://awk.info/?tip/getline and can accept the consequences when you are pulling your hair out trying to enhance your script later.

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look. I suspect the issue with my script is PEBCAK related :)

Comment: @fembot - look again. In most awks the posted script will duplicate the last line of your input if that last line does not contain the >>updated flag since the getline failure on that last line should not set $0. In some awks I suppose the getline failure may set $0 to the NULL string in which case you'll get a blank line at the end of your input. The posted script CANNOT produce the desired output as shown given your posted sample input. getline caveats strike again...

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;s/.*\n(.*)\s+>>updated\s*$/\1/;P;D' file
```

Keep two lines in the pattern space and delete the first when the last matches you requirements.

An awk solution might be:

```
awk 'sub(/ *>>updated.*/,""){l=$0;next};NR>1{print l};{l=$0};END{print l}' file
```

Comment: I'm a little rough with sed. I understand how to do a substitution, but I've only done it with a single line so far. How do I keep two lines in the pattern space?

Comment: @fembot the sed command `N` reads the next line into the pattern space and separates it from the current line with a newline `\n`. The command `$!N` means except for the last always read in the next line. Used in conjuction with `P` and `D` which print/delete upto the first newline, these commands allows sed to process a 2 line window as it flows through file.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to go play around with this now.

Comment: @fembot don't waste your time, this is absolutely NOT a job for sed, it's a job for awk, perl, ruby, etc.

Answer (score 3):

`tac` is nice but not default for all distributions. In case you don't have it available, here is an awk single process one-liner:

```
awk -F' >>' 'p{if($2~/updated/){p=$1;next}print p}{p=$0}END{print p}' file
```

Comment: I worded my initial query incorrectly. If my current row is ">>updated", I want to remove the row right before it and replace that with the values in the ">>updated" row.

Comment: @fembot my script does what you said, the output is exactly same as the one in your question.

Comment: +1 for the right approach if memory is a significant concern.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'if(/\>\>updated/){pop @a;s/\>\>updated//g;push @a,$_}else{push @a,$_}END{print join "\n",@a}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
AAA BBB CCC1
DDD EEE FFF1
GGG HHH III1
GGG HHH III3 >>updated
JJJ KKK LLL7
> perl -lne 'if(/\>\>updated/){pop @a;s/\>\>updated//g;push @a,$_}else{push @a,$_}END{print join "\n",@a}' temp
AAA BBB CCC1
DDD EEE FFF1
GGG HHH III3 
JJJ KKK LLL7
>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to build up an array of the lines in your input file but only increase the array index when >>updated is absent so that lines that do contain >>updated overwrite the previous entry in the array and then just print the contents of the array when you get to the end of file:

```
$ cat file
AAA BBB CCC1
DDD EEE FFF1
GGG HHH III1           <----- I want to remove this
GGG HHH III3 >>updated <----- I want to keep this
JJJ KKK LLL7

$ awk '!/>>updated/{++numLines} {line[numLines]=$0} END {for (nr=1;nr<=numLines;nr++) print line[nr]}' file
AAA BBB CCC1
DDD EEE FFF1
GGG HHH III3 >>updated <----- I want to keep this
JJJ KKK LLL7
```

If you want to get rid of the >>updated and subsequent text on that line, you can change the test for it's existence to a test for an attempt to remove it:

```
$ awk '!sub(/ *>>updated.*/,""){++numLines} {line[numLines]=$0} END{for (nr=1;nr<=numLines;nr++) print line[nr]}' file
AAA BBB CCC1
DDD EEE FFF1
GGG HHH III3
JJJ KKK LLL7
```

If >>updated was present then the sub() will remove it and return success so you know that >>updated was present, otherwise the sub() will do nothing but return fail so you know that >>updated was absent.